# JPA query with several relations and mapped parameters

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I'm programming a webserver in Glassfish for ads. Each **ad** has a **category** and a **place**. Each category or place might have subcategories/subplaces.

I want to select ads whitin a *category-tree* and a *place-tree*.  The entity classes I have created for this scenario are shown below.

The category entity:

```
@Entity
public class Category {

    @Id 
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="category")
    List<Ad> ads;

    @Basic
    private String path;
}
```

The place entity:

```
@Entity
public class Place {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="place")
    List<Ad> ads;

    @Basic
    private String path;
}
```

The Ad entity:

```
@Entity
public class Ad {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    Category category;

    @ManyToOne
    Place place;
```

So I added a field/column named  *path* for the category and the place. This *path* is a string which must begin with its parents *path*. So if I wanted to find all ads whitin a category and a place, then I would do this following pseudo-query:

```
SELECT a from Ad a WHERE Category.pathid "STARTS WITH" getCategoryPathByID(PARAMETER 1) 
                   AND Place.pathid "STARTS WITH" getPlacePathByID(PARAMETER 2)
```

I have hard time figuring out how to accomplish this with a JPA query because I dont know how to join the category & place tables and how to match the *path* given the *id*.

Can anyone help me how to build this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to join the category & place tables. You can filter the ads through the relations to categoy and place, something like this:

```
select a from Ad a where a.category.pathid like 'x' and a.place.pathid like 'x'
```

The Ad is the way you can relate the category and place tables, maybe something like this could be useful

```
select a from Category c join c.ads a join a.place p
where c.pathid like ''
and p.pathid like ''
```

In this query there are joins between the 3 tables, and it apply a filter by the category and place.